# How to take all integer data from a database column and transform it into float in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I'm taking a data science course and I came across an exercise that left me confused.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
jeopardy = pd.read_csv('jeopardy.csv')
jeopardy.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)

print(jeopardy.head())
```

This is the OUTPUT:
[image]

here is one that is being recognized as an object, because it has values ​​like this: "$200.00", I am trying to take the integer values ​​of this column and transform them into floats:

```
jeopardy["Value_float"] = jeopardy['Value'].apply(lambda x: float(x[1:].replace(',',"")))
```

When I try to create a table an error appears, but it doesn't make sense and I don't know what to do to fix it.

```
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). And please, always provide the whole traceback so we don't guess which line generates the error.

Comment: Are you sure all values in the "value" column are strings? The error says your trying  subscript (use square brackets) on a float object, which is not allowed. You can subscript on a string though.

Comment: pd.read_csv will gives strings but error message is saying you have a float. What does `print(jeopardy.dtypes)` show you?

Comment: the "Value" column has type "object".

Comment: you likely have a mix of floats and strings in your column. It's relatively easy to tackle.

Comment: I don't know what's happening, I tried running this same code here at home and at work. It didn't work here but at work it did, without making any changes!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

jeopardy = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [4680, "2004-12-31", "Jeopardy!", "HISTORY", "$200", "For the last 8 years of his life, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man's theory", "Copernicus"],
        [4680, "2004-12-31", "Jeopardy!", "ESPN's TOP ALL-TIME ATHLETES", "$200", "No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves", "Jim Thorpe"],
        [4680, "2004-12-31", "Jeopardy!", "EVERYBODY TALKS ABOUT IT...", "$200", "The city of Yuma in this state has a record average of 4,055 hours of sunshine each year", "Arizona"],
        [4680, "2004-12-31", "Jeopardy!", "THE COMPANY LINE", "$1,300.50", 'In 1963, live on "The Art Linkletter Show", this company served its billionth burger', "McDonald's"],
        [4680, "2004-12-31", "Jeopardy!", "EPITAPHS & TRIBUTES", "$ 1,200 ", "Signer of the Dec. of Indep., framer of the Constitution of Mass., second President of the United States", "John Adams"],
    ],
    columns=["Show Number", "Air Date", "Round", "Category", "Value", "Question", "Answer"]
)
jeopardy.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)

# Convert values to float by first removing the "$" sign and the "," (thousands separator).
# Then call `pandas.to_numeric()` function with `errors="coerce"` to convert values to numeric,
# and values that fail to convert to `None`.
jeopardy["Value_float"] = pd.to_numeric(jeopardy['Value'].str.replace("$", "", regex=False).str.replace(",", "", regex=False), errors="coerce")

# Find the values that failed to convert to float
errors = jeopardy[jeopardy["Value_float"].isna()]

jeopardy
```

**Output:**

| Show Number | Air Date | Round | Category | Value | Question | Answer | Value_float |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4680 | 2004-12-31 | Jeopardy! | HISTORY | $200 | For the last 8 years of his life, Galileo was under house arrest for espousing this man's theory | Copernicus | 200 |
| 4680 | 2004-12-31 | Jeopardy! | ESPN's TOP ALL-TIME ATHLETES | $200 | No. 2: 1912 Olympian; football star at Carlisle Indian School; 6 MLB seasons with the Reds, Giants & Braves | Jim Thorpe | 200 |
| 4680 | 2004-12-31 | Jeopardy! | EVERYBODY TALKS ABOUT IT... | $200 | The city of Yuma in this state has a record average of 4,055 hours of sunshine each year | Arizona | 200 |
| 4680 | 2004-12-31 | Jeopardy! | THE COMPANY LINE | $1,300.50 | In 1963, live on "The Art Linkletter Show", this company served its billionth burger | McDonald's | 1300.5 |
| 4680 | 2004-12-31 | Jeopardy! | EPITAPHS & TRIBUTES | $ 1,200 | Signer of the Dec. of Indep., framer of the Constitution of Mass., second President of the United States | John Adams | 1200 |

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this would work? It lets numbers go through (and become `float` if they aren't float yet), but it removes unwanted characters:

```py
import re

def to_float(x):
    if isinstance(x, str):
        x = re.sub('[$,%]', '', x)
    return float(x)
```

Example:

```py
v = ['$2,000.00', '12', 1, 1_500, '-$14']
>>> pd.Series(v).apply(to_float)
0    2000.0
1      12.0
2       1.0
3    1500.0
4     -14.0
```